# Rigorous proof that if $G$ is planar, connected and not a tree, then the boundary of every face contains a cycle

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a planar connected graph with a fixed embedding. Then if $G$ is not a tree, how to prove that the boundary of every face contains at least one cycle?

Seems to me quite difficult to find the right "topological" arguments in $\mathbb R^2$. Intuitively, if the boundary of some face does not contain a cycle, then this face is not "separated" from other faces, hence we just have one face, and our connected graph must be a tree. But this kind of argument is to informell, how to make it formal by arguing with the embedding, properties of $\mathbb R^2$ (Jordan curves and so on...)?

*EDIT*: Regarding the comment of looking at a sequence when traversing the edges (or vertices) in a specific order, that would not give me necessarily a cycle, see the picture below where this sequence ends (or when I go on the first repetition would not give a cycle).

[image]

Comment: One approach would be to travel around the boundary of a face (say counter-clockwise), and as you travel along the boundary record the vertices and edges you encounter with a sequence, e.g. $v_0, e_1, v_1, e_2,v_2,\dots, ..., v_{n-1},e_{n}, v_{n}$ where $v_{n}=v_0$. Then think about what can happen in the boundary of a face and prune the sequence to eliminate everything except for a cycle.

Comment: @AdamLowrance Thanks for your comment, I also thought about something like that. But I guess it is not guaranteed that I have a repetition in the sequence when I proceed like you suggest, see the picture I put in the question as a response to your comment!

Comment: You started drawing a curve that traces out the boundary of the face, but you ended it at a vertex of degree one. Instead of doing that, wrap around the vertex of degree one, and continue back along the other side of the vertical edge. I will label vertices $v_0, \dots, v_5$ and edges $e_0,\dots, e_5$. I will complete the path you drew, and choose a label for the vertex/edge that is the smallest non-chosen label. Then the sequence of my first comment for your example is $v_0, e_0, v_1, e_1, v_2, e_1,v_1, e_2,v_3,e_3,v_4,e_3,v_3,e_4,v_4,e_5,v_0$. Can you find the cycle inside this sequence?

Comment: @AdamLowrance But just looking for repeating vertices gives "fake" cylces as for $v_1$ in the example, and I see no way how to exclude them that works in all cases?

Comment: You can remove trees attached to the boundary by repeatedly applying the following operation. If you see a subsequence $e_i, v_j, e_i$ in the sequence, then delete the subsequence and repeat the process. That kills a leaf and the edge incident to it. Once you have no such subsequences, there will be no trees attached to the boundary. At the end of this process the boundary may still not be a cycle. You have to handle cases where the graph has more than one [block](https://goo.gl/oDQQrC). Consider the example in my response to your previous [question](https://goo.gl/18RsGt).

Comment: @AdamLowrance Okay, by your procedure I can be sure I do not have "dead ends", i.e. from every vertex there is always an edge leading to a different vertex which is also adjacent to the same face, and as there are just finitely many vertices there must occur a repetition, which then gives a cycle. But what has this to do with your remark regarding blocks?

Comment: My point is that trees attached to the boundary are not the only bad thing we have to take care of. If a graph is not 2-connected, then it can be decomposed into blocks. The outer face of the linked example in my previous comment is not a cycle, but contains two cycles. You have to work out a way to identify the cycles inside of the vertex/edge sequence.

Comment: @AdamLowrance Every subsequence that starts and ends at the same vertex without containing any edge twice is a "true" cycle?

Comment: That’s correct. You can either argue that at least one such subsequence must exist (when considering the sequence up to cyclic permutation) or you can argue how to remove edges that appear twice before returning to the original vertex.